# indexed db is not working in opera,safari

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
 if (!("indexedDB" in window)) {
            console.warn("IndexedDB not supported");
            return;
        }
        log("db created ",data.product_detail)
    
        const dbName = "gt_form";
        const storeName = "product_store";
        const version = 1; //versions start at 1
    
            const db = await openDB(dbName, version, {
            upgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion, transaction) {
            const store = db.createObjectStore(storeName);
            }
        });
        
        const tx = await db.transaction(storeName, "readwrite");
        const store = await tx.objectStore(storeName);
```

its working fine on mozila and chrome but don't know why rest of the browser is not supporting ven chrome incognito mode also